# grouping an array separated by empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 422
    [F] => IDR
    [G] =>   5,945,193,025,500.00 
    [H] => 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 421
    [F] => IDR
    [G] => 
    [H] =>   5,945,193,025,500.00 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 
    [C] => 
    [F] => 
    [G] => 
    [H] => 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 4945
    [F] => IDR
    [G] =>   406,630,911,282.00 
    [H] => 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 228
    [F] => IDR
    [G] => 
    [H] =>   406,630,911,282.00 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 
    [B] => 
    [C] => 
    [F] => 
    [G] => 
    [H] => 
)
```

and i want result like this

```
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 422
    [F] => IDR
    [G] =>   5,945,193,025,500.00 
    [H] => 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 421
    [F] => IDR
    [G] => 
    [H] =>   5,945,193,025,500.00 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 2
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 4945
    [F] => IDR
    [G] =>   406,630,911,282.00 
    [H] => 
)
Array
(
    [A] => 2
    [B] => 700
    [C] => 228
    [F] => IDR
    [G] => 
    [H] =>   406,630,911,282.00 
)
```

add ID at `[A]` with separated by an empty array

this array come from this code :

```
$array = array_chunk($sheetData, 1); 
foreach($array as $chunk) { 
    foreach($chunk as $subarray) { 
        echo "<pre>"; 
        print_r($subarray); 
        echo "</pre>";
     } 
}
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: this array come from this code : 
<pre>
$array = array_chunk($sheetData, 1);
foreach($array as $chunk)
{
    foreach($chunk as $subarray)
    {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($subarray);
            echo "</pre>";

    }
}
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$in =
[
    [
        'a'=> null,
        'b'=> 'foo'
    ],
    [],
    [
        'a'=> null,
        'b'=> 'bar'
    ],
    [
        'a'=> null,
        'b'=> 'baz'
    ],
    [],
    [
        'a'=> null,
        'b'=> 'bat'
    ]    
];

$out     = [];
$counter = 1;
foreach($in as $array) {
    if(empty($array)) {
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $array['a'] = $counter;
        $out[]      = $array;
    }
}

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 'foo',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 'bar',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 'baz',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 'bat',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thx, but what I wanted is the $counter is same number not count on loop, its count only with separate empty array *sorry for my English

Comment: If you try the code, you'll see that the counter only increments when it encounters an empty array element, not on every loop.   Check the input and output above.